# postfix mail server unable to receive mails

Tags: postfix, email-server, gmail, mail-forwarding

I have setup a mail server on my localhost (ubuntu) machine using postfix. which is connected to a modem.

I have acquired a static ip from my isp, which is 106.51.43.121

I have made sure that my ubuntu machine that it is listening on port  25 and 587 for the domain jestasoft.com which is linked to the local ip address 192.168.1.104 in the /etc/hosts file

The "/etc/hosts" which has

> 192.168.1.104  jestasoft.com

I have just purchased the domain name jestasoft.com from a hosting provider. And in the dns records i have made an entry for mx records which links to smtp.jestasoft.com

And an A record pointing jestasoft.com to 106.51.43.121(my static ip) which is linked to my router which forwards to 192.168.1.104

Now I have 2 problems

1. I am not able to send mails to external domains
2. And I am also unable to receive any mails from external domains

I have so far found that the first problem is because my static ip is listed in PBL which blocks a list of ip addresses meant for dynamic ip addresses. I will be only be able to come accross this problem if i am able to receive a 5 digit code on my domain i.e. jestasoft.com

But unfortunately i am not even able to receive mails from external domains. I tried to send a mail from my google email address to jestasoft.com

I get an error message

> Technical details of temporary failure:
>   DNS Error: 154015175 DNS type 'mx' lookup ofjestasoft.com responded with code NOERROR
>   154015175 DNS type 'aaaa' lookup ofsmtp.jestasoft.com. responded with code NXDOMAIN
>   154015175 DNS type 'a' lookup of smtp.jestasoft.com. responded with code NXDOMAIN

Comment: Why add that entry to /etc/hosts?

Comment: I have added that to be able to listen for hostname jestasoft.com on the ip address 192.168.1.104 and it is totally my perception. Actually the guide which i referred while setting up postfix instructed me to add something like "127.0.0.2 <hostname> . Please bare with me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is your DNS zone.** You can see below `smtp.jestasoft.com` is your mail exchanger (smtp host), however **it does not have an A record** (it's not defined).

```
jestasoft.com.          21599   IN      MX      0 smtp.jestasoft.com.
jestasoft.com.          21599   IN      NS      dns2.bigrock.in.
jestasoft.com.          7199    IN      SOA     dns1.bigrock.in. rakshithskumar1988.gmail.com. 2016082002 7200 7200 172800 38400
jestasoft.com.          21599   IN      A       106.51.43.121
jestasoft.com.          21599   IN      NS      dns4.bigrock.in.
jestasoft.com.          21599   IN      NS      dns3.bigrock.in.
jestasoft.com.          21599   IN      NS      dns1.bigrock.in.
```

**Not found = can't receive mail**

```
$ host smtp.jestasoft.com
Host smtp.jestasoft.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

**You need to add a DNS entry like this**:

```
smtp.jestasoft.com. IN A 106.51.43.121
```

**Then check your DNS** it should look like this:

```
$ host -tmx entrenet.com
jestasoft.com mail is handled by 0 smtp.jestasoft.com.
$ host smtp.jestasoft.com
smtp.jestasoft.com has address 106.51.43.121
```

**The next step is to verify your mail server is responding** without actually sending an email though gmail or whatever... you can do that later.

One way is to **telnet to port 25 and 587** and see if Postfix welcomes you. This is an example with my server:

```
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to smtp.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp ESMTP
```

**This site can do some checks** for you too, though I personally prefer to do things myself:

http://mxtoolbox.com/

Once you're sure your DNS is correct, you can try sending an actual email through another email system (like you did with gmail).

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks a lot for the quick and detailed description of my problem. I actually want to change the mx record to mail.jestasoft.com from smtp.jestasoft.com and i made the necessary changes. I added an A record as you suggested to link mail.jestasoft.com to my ip which can be verified using " host mail.jestasoft.com" but now the problem is with mx record tough i changed it to mail.jestasoft.com, i get the mail server as smtp.jestasoft.com with "host -tmx" and also "dig" commands. Please tell me if there is a way to clear dns record cache

Comment: @RakshithSKumar `host -t mx jestasoft.com dns2.bigrock.in` returns `jestasoft.com mail is handled by 0 mail.jestasoft.com.`. So you'll just need to wait for that information to propagate to other DNS servers as the old record expires. Or use DNS servers that don't have your old zone info cached.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I am sure that i have made some progress, coz i am able to connect using thunderbird client. all thanks to you. But i guess, I have made some blunder while trying to fix the above issue with postfix configuration. Waiting for gmail to bounce back. I have accepted the answer.

Comment: @RakshithSKumar Good luck, hopefully it's something simple. If you find a new problem and need help, post  a new question.